# ld: library not found for -lvtkftgl

Tags: macos, vtk, point-cloud-library

I'm trying to compile pcl program and I already done the installation of pcl using homebrew. I'm using Mac OSX 10.10.5 and command line to compile the program. At "make" step I got this error

ld: library not found for -lvtkftgl
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

what could be the problems, and possibly solutions. I really appreciated it if anyone help me with this. Thanx in advance.

Answer (score 1):

You can also install the latest PCL version.

```
brew install --HEAD pcl
```

Answer (score 0):

So I had this issue as well; seems like the VTK library does not work well with pcl at this moment. A temporary solution is to install pcl without the VTK library, and you can compile and run their tutorial fine.

Run the following:

`$ brew uninstall pcl`

`$ brew install pcl --without-apps --without-tools --without-vtk --without-qt # this will take a while, so be patient here`

Now, follow the tutorial here: http://www.pointclouds.org/documentation/tutorials/using_pcl_pcl_config.php#using-pcl-pcl-config

You should be able to compile and run their tutorial fine.

Comment: Thank you Frank, I found out many problems actually in my computer and I couldn't get the pcl working, so I had to switch to linux. but thank again for you help :)

Answer (score 0):

Here is a temporary fix:

```
brew uninstall pcl
brew install https://raw.githubusercontent.com/ahundt/homebrew-science/vtk6/vtk6.rb --build-from-source
brew install https://raw.githubusercontent.com/ahundt/homebrew-science/vtk6/pcl.rb --build-from-source
```

Here is a discussion of this particular issue:

```
https://github.com/mikepurvis/ros-install-osx/issues/32
```

Here is where I'm trying to submit my fix to homebrew-science. Feel free to encourage them to break the particularly esoteric impasse that's occurring there!

```
https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-science/pull/3512
```